# Is it necessary to provide images for all dpi folders?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-drawable, dpi

I would like to use an image as background in one of my activities.

I know that you are supposed to provide different image sizes in the different dpi folders, however I noticed that if I provide only a 1080x1920 image in the xxhdpi folder everything seems to be working ok. By that I mean that the image seems to be correctly downsized for screens with lower dpis and I don't see any weird memory fluctuations when I profile.

So is it really necessary to provide all different sizes or can I just provide a higher res one in the xxhdpi folder and let Android take care of the rest?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just provide all high resolution images and it'll work fine.

BUT: On lower resolution screens, the high resolution image will simply be downscaled, but still take up the same amount of memory as the high resolution image.

And lower resolution screens generally mean lower specs = lower RAM, thus you could run into complications with your app taking up too much memory.

I generally provide different resolution images for icons and smaller items, but provide 1 high resolution image for large backgrounds and such. I like this compromise personally.

Comment: Thanks, is it certain that it will still take up the same amount of memory? I was under the impression that it was downsampling it too, since I didn't see anything weird in memory usage when I tried it in lower memory devices.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not., but it's recommended. You can play with sizes from your XML and Java, the only problems could be the weight of your application (if you only attach images with a high resolution), and the quality of your images (on the other way)